# Can I use still use blender 2.79?

Tags: game-engine

Currently I am still using the blender 2.79 version. Can use the game engine of blender 2.79 to make and publish games?

Comment: No it’s is not duplicated. It’s is not at all same with that question.

Comment: Sure you can. Just keep in mind that no updates and fixes will be released anymore, so use at your own risk. I actually use it with no complaints (along with UPBGE 0.2.5b).

Comment: Means can I use the games made in it for commercial purpose? I mean can I publish the games without any cost?

Comment: You always could, there's just some caveats. See some details about licensing here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/game_engine/licensing.html

Comment: Of course you can still use Blender 2.79 & its game-engine. No one can stop you from downloading it. But you could also use a UPBGE 0.3x or 0.2x release for more optimal and bug free software.